# Qt Serial Port echos input

Tags: c++, linux, qt, serial-port

I have a gateway device plugged into /dev/ttyUSB0.  When I use screen and send a command, I only get the response from the gateway.  However, in my Qt program, (using Qt Serial Port), my command is always echoed back to me.  I disabled echo on the device using `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -echo` and then printed out the flags:

```
stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0

speed 19200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;

intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;

eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;

rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 0; time = 0;

-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts

-ignbrk -brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr 

-icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8

-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel 

nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0

-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh

-xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

This shows that `-echo` is set. (echo is not set)

There is a similar problem here: [linux-c-serial-port-echoes-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506836/linux-c-serial-port-echoes-output).  However it looks like it was never solved and I tried some of the suggestions there.  I could ignore the first input line, but I would prefer to not deal with it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to check the configuration *while your program is running*, your serial wrapper doesn't necessarily leave settings at their prior values.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried to run stty while my program was running, but I get a "device busy" response.

Comment: @MrUser: Well yes, you'll have to do it from inside the program, using the termios functions on your open file descriptor.